# Running shell script from PHP as different (non root) user

Tags: php, linux, permissions, exec

I'm trying to run a shell script owned by a non-privileged user from PHP on an Ubuntu server. Issues with permissions make running it with `exec()` impractical, as it's `www-data` that's running it. I've googled a bit and found varius references to suExec (which seems too much of a hassle to get working for such a small problem), setting the suid bit, and an interesting approach here on Stackoverflow involving a Python server listening for commands sent by PHP.

Anyway, of all of these solutions, I lean towards the one involving setting the suid bit, tried it and it didn't work : `chmod u+s script.sh`, and my Apache logs still show permission errors, so I know the script is not running as it's owner but as `www-data`.

What do I have to do to get this working, and is there a simpler solution for this problem ?

Comment: No. Your user (www-data) needs execution rights to run the script. What is the root problem that makes you want to use a shell script, maybe that has a useful answer.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create an in-house version of http://php.opensourcecms.com/ (Demos of open-source CMSs that are automatically reset at some time inverval). I've already got cron running as the non-privileged user running the script every 2 hours, but I'd like to add functionnality to execute it on demand. I could run it as www-data, but that means I also have it to run from www-data's cron, since the replaced files are owned by www-data. Anyway, I'd like to avoid having www-data owning all the files for security reasons.

Comment: Deletes the CMS's directory, untar backup, delete / create / import database backup, and that's about it...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the man page for sudo: `sudo -u your_other_user` will let you execute the command as the other user.

Also use man sudoers to look for options on which user can execute what commands with sudo.

Comment: Looking into your solution but so far no luck in getting it to work. I've tried enabling password-less sudo for the specific command that's supposed to run in the sudoers file : `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /user/bin/sudo -u user /path/to/command` But if I `su www-data` and try to run it still asks for a password. Same with `/user/bin/sudo -u user`

Comment: `sudo: the -U option may only be used with the -l option`

Comment: Note that it's smallcase -u not -U (see sudo --help)