# Executing a program from PHP script

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to execute the command `exec('vlc');` 
from php script (in linux), 
but then, the page (php) has not been loaded.
Even by using pcntl_fork (for exec command) this is not working.

But if I am trying to run from command line `php -S localhost:8000 -t path/to/src`,
and enter `localhost:8000/page.php` in the browser, the page has been loaded and the vlc opened.

What is the problem ?

Note:
 If I am trying to run from command line `php -r "exec('vlc');"` the vlc opened.

In addition, I checked and the php not working in safe mode.

**Update1:**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('vlc');
?>
```

****    **not working**   ****

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('vlc 2>&1');
?>
```

**The output:**

**Home directory not accessible: Permission denied [08ea1490] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused [08e9e448] core interface error: no suitable interface module [08ded0d0] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed [08e9e448] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 [08e9e448] core interface error: no suitable interface module [08ded0d0] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed [08ded0d0] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. [08e9e448] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server [08e9e448] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory [08e9e448] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console". VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('whoami');
?>
```

**The output: www-data**

```
/var/log/httpd
```

**not exists**

but `/var/log/apache2/error.log`  exists and:

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
[0980c490] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[09809448] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[097580d0] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[09809448] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[09809448] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[097580d0] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[097580d0] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[09809448] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
[09809448] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[09809448] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
[09809448] [cli] lua interface: Requested shutdown.
```

**Update2:**

```
shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0  vlc");
```

working, but very slowly (with `php -S ...` , is faster).

**I trying**

```
 shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0  vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '.settings.'");
```

(with some settings) but I received an error

```
[b4602c50] mux_ogg mux: Open
[b4604a30] v4l2 demux error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
[b4604a30] v4l2 demux error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
[b4604a30] v4l2 access error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
[b4b04ea0] core input error: open of `v4l2:///dev/video0' failed
[b4b04ea0] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[b4b04ea0] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'. Check the log for details.
[b4602c50] mux_ogg mux: Close
```

but with `php -S ...` is working .

What is the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to post comments, which makes debugging a little bit difficult. First check your your error log in /var/log/httpd and see if there is anything obvious there. If there is nothing there, Can you execute this and tell us if this does anything?

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('vlc');
?>
```

if this does nothing do

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('vlc 2>&1');
?>
```

and

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('whoami');
?>
```

Comment: Execute it as a user that has x11 configured. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149341/running-shell-script-from-php-as-different-non-root-user

Comment: do full on `sudo -u some_user vlc` , and change your permissions on sudo to allow www-data to run `sudo -u some_user vlc`

Comment: No, this is not working. And what do you mean  by "change your permissions on sudo to allow www-data" ?

Comment: In order to change user without having to type a password you have to either go through a lot of configuration or do it with sudo. By default, www-data is not allowed to run any sudo commands, and if you try to do anything with sudo using shell_exec, you will either get a prompt for password, or see a warning of some sort... 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/allow-a-normal-user-to-run-commands-as-root.html